# View specs have no render method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I’m trying to write some view specs that test some template logic. I’m following the instructions in the RSpec book, and also checking other online references. I don’t seem to have access to `render` or `assign`.

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "projects/index.html.erb" do

  it "displays an entry for each project" do
    projects = 5.times { FactoryGirl.create :project }
    render
    expect(all(".project-index-entry").count).to eq 5
  end

end
```

When I run the above, I get:

```
 Failure/Error: render
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `render' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProjectsIndexHtmlErb:0x007fa2950d4140>
 # ./spec/views/projects/index.html.erb_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The same thing happens if I try to use `assign`. I know I could use `visit`, but then I would have to simulate the act of the user signing in before each spec. I may be misunderstood, but I think the render method is meant to be more isolated, allowing me to skip the authentication check I have in the controller.

So, why don’t I have the view spec methods I was expecting?

```
Versions:
 - capybara 2.4.1
 - rails 4.1.0
 - rspec-core 3.1.3
 - rspec-expectations 3.1.1
 - rspec-mocks 3.1.0
 - rspec-rails 3.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I updated rspec some time ago and the previous version used a significantly different `spec_helper`. After the update, the logic was split into `spec_helper` and `rails_helper`, so to fix this problem I had to rerun `rails generate rspec:install`.